# Making a daily repeating notification but with randomized content each time

Tags: android, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

What i am trying to do here is to randomize the notification's content each time it pops up. But i have no idea how to implement that, here's what my current code looks like:

**Main2Activity**

```
public void startAlarm() {

    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent myIntent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    myIntent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,myIntent,0);

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+0,86400000,pendingIntent);
}
```

---

Here is my receiver class:

**AlarmNotificationReceiver**

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder2 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder3 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    builder1.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm 1 actived!")
            .setContentText("THIS IS MY ALARM")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    builder2.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm 2 actived!")
            .setContentText("THIS IS MY ALARM")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    builder3.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Alarm 3 actived!")
            .setContentText("THIS IS MY ALARM")
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentInfo("Info");

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1,builder1.build());
}
}
```

My problem here is in this bottom part...

[image]

How can I make it random each time the alarm triggers?

Comment: What kind of randomization? you should explain more.

Comment: The randomization i want there is, whenever the `onReceive()` is called. In the three builders(`buider1`, `buider2`, `buider3`) one builder will be called in order to create the notification.

Comment: You can generate random number and trigger the notification builder according to the number you got.

Comment: Already done that, idk if that works in background because it only shows the `builder1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Random` class for generating random objects (booleans, integers,... etc) then `swtich` the generated number and notify with the suitable notification.

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
switch(random.nextInt(3)){
    case 0:
        // notify builder 1
        break;
    case 1:
        // notify builder 2
        break;
    case 2:
        // notify builder 3
        break;
}
```

I really recommend refactoring your code as there is no need to create 3 identical objects with many common attributes where you can use only one and change its content according to the case you got from the random generator. Below is an example

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

builder.setAutoCancel(true)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);

Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
switch (random.nextInt(3)) {
    case 0:
        builder.setContentTitle("Alarm 1 activated!")
                .setContentText("THIS IS MY ALARM")
                .setContentInfo("Info");
        break;
    case 1:
        builder.setContentTitle("Alarm 2 activated!")
                .setContentText("THIS IS MY ALARM")
                .setContentInfo("Info");
        break;
    case 2:
        builder.setContentTitle("Alarm 3 activated!")
                .setContentText("THIS IS MY ALARM")
                .setContentInfo("Info");
        break;
}

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```